# awk compare two scientific float numbers

Tags: bash, awk, compare

i have the following problem with awk:

code:

```
var=1.16000e-02
size=1.10e-02
foo=$(awk -v this="${var}" -v trg="$size" 'BEGIN { out=0; if(this=trg) out=1;printf "%i", out; exit(0)}')
```

sh -x gives me the following statement:

```
+ awk -v this=1.16000e-02 -v trg=1.10e-02 BEGIN { out=0; if(this=trg) out=1;printf "%i", out; exit(0)}
+ foo=1
```

Why is `foo=1` if obviously this is not equal to `trg`?

Answer (score 2):

With

```
if(this=trg)
```

you set the value of variable `trg` to the value of variable `this` and that should be true, you did it yourself. You should

```
if(this==trg)
```

Comment: woopsie, its too late. Thanks !

Comment: What does `woopsie, its too late` mean?